# Does JSplitPane.setRightComponent() method automatically destroys previously set object?

Tags: java, swing, memory

I am writing a java swing application in which I have a JSplitPane (splitPane). At first a JPanel (say SummaryPanel) is added to it.
Now, from SummaryPanel, I'm getting a reference to parent JSplitPane sp and setting a different JPanel on button click.

When, I looked at the task manager, everytime I click and a JPanel is set, the application's memory usage increases and doesn't drops off.

Here's what an example program looks like:

Inside main JFrame:

```
JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane();
sp.getLeftComponent().setVisible(false);
sp.setRightComponent(new SummaryPanel());
```

Inside SummaryPanel:

```
myBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JSplitPane parent = (JSplitPane) getParent();
            parent.setRightComponent(new MyPanel());
        }
});
```

Is their any better way of doing this?
Or, maybe any way I could possibly reduce the memory usage.

Comment: *"he application's memory usage increases and doesn't drops off"*  Unless you are in danger of running out of memory, ignore it.  You can be pretty sure the JVM will.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (and put that 'remove/add' code in a loop).

Comment: @andrew-thompson: OK, thanks I got it...
Better understood by this article:
[link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)